# Export Revit file format as Gltf or Svf and view offline in Forge-Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I want to view the revit file offline in Forge viwer. For this, I need to convert the rvt file to svf or gltf file format. I couldn't find any free open source code to export as svf. Although I managed to export it as a gltf file format, I could not view this gltf file in forge-viewer due to some errors that I could not resolve. Can you share the open source code that I can use to export the Revit file as svf or gltf format without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The SVF file format is Autodesk's private property designed for the Autodesk Forge platform, so the only way of exporting SVF is via [Forge Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/). There is no such open source tool to generate SVF.

For glTF, it depends on your Gltf file structure. As I know, Forge Viewer doesn't fully support glTF 2.0 specs. See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer

Could you share a non-confidential reproducible glTF file demonstrating the issue to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`? We can help pass it to our engineering team for investigation.